# Python - capture number that follows matched word on previous line

Tags: python, string, email

I have an `.eml` file that appears to have data on the same line...but in my simple straightforward attempts to parse it, it is clear that it isn't all on the same line.

Here is what the email looks like when I open it:

[image]

but when trying the following code:

```
with open(file_path) as f:
    for line in f:
         if ("Haddock") in line:
            print(line)
```

the printout is only:

`GB Haddock West` and doesn't include `22572`

Simply copying and pasting the email body into notepad will place those two values several lines apart. So I am ideally looking for a method that says "if **X** is found, capture the next number, whether it is on the same line or the next line"

Is that possible?

The code I'm actually looking to use, by the way, is: `if any(stock.lower() in line.lower().strip() for stock in stocks):` which is checking to see if any of the 30+ fish stocks appear in the email, then proceed.

So if any of the fish below appear, then capture the number that follows it:

```
stocks = (
        'GB COD EAST',
        'GBE COD',
        'GB COD WEST',
        'GBW COD',
        'GOM COD',
        'GB HADDOCK EAST',
        'GBE HADD',
        'GB HADDOCK WEST',
        'GBW HADD',
        'GOM HADDOCK',
        'GOM HADD',
        'GOM HAD',
        'GOM HADOCK',
        'PLAICE',
        'DABS',
        'POLLOCK',
        'POLL',
        'REDFISH',
        'REDS',
        'RED',
        'WHITE HAKE' ,
        'WHITEHAKE',
        'WHAKE',
        'WHAK',
        'GB WINTER FLOUNDER',
        'GB BB',
        'GB WINTER',
        'GB BLACK BACKS',
        'GB BLACKBACKS',
        'GOM WINTER FLOUNDER',
        'GOM BLACKBACKS',
        'GOM BB',
        'GOM WINTER',
        'SNE WINTER FLOUNDER',
        'SNE WINTER',
        'SNE/MA WINTER FLOUNDER',
        'SNE BLACKBACK',
        'SNE BLACKBACKS',
        'SNE BB',
        'WITCH FLOUNDER',
        'WITCH',
        'WHICH',
        'WHITCH',
        'GREYSOLE',
        'GREY SOLE',
        'CC/GOM YELLOWTAIL FLOUNDER',
        'GOM YELLOWTAIL',
        'GOM YELLOW TAIL',
        'GOM YT',
        'GB YELLOWTAIL FLOUNDER',
        'GB YELLOWTAIL',
        'GB YT',
        'SNE/MA YELLOWTAIL FLOUNDER',
        'SNE YT',
        'SNE YELLOWTAIL',
        'SNE YELLOW TAIL',
        'SCALLOP IFQ'
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression in multiline mode to search for your pattern across lines. Use two capture groups. The first is a union of the items in your `stocks` list and the second is a contiguous sequence of digits.

The whole technique is fragile because it falls apart if this email contains the search word outside of the pattern you want. Consider using the `email` module to crack the file open and pull out the message body or whatever attachment has the data. But this will do what you want:

```
import re

fishy_re = re.compile(r'({}).*?(\d+)'.format('|'.join(stocks)),
    re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

with open(file_path) as f:
    for match in fishy_re.finditer(f.read()):
        fish, count = match.groups()
        print(fish, count)
```

That regex is something of a black box. Taking a simpler example, consider

```
>>> stocks = ['COD', 'TUNA']
>>> regex_str = '({}).*?(\d+)'.format('|'.join(stocks))
>>> regex_str
'(COD|TUNA).*?(\\d+)'
```

- `(COD|TUNA)` finds anything in the union (COD or TUNA), and remembers its position.
- `.*?` is a non-greedy capture of all following characters... as long as they don't fit the next pattern. This will consume everything up to the next digit.
- `(\d+)` finds one or more digits and remembers its position.

We end up with two capture groups containing the fish name and count.

Comment: Ok so is there a way to use this RegEx method with the long list of stocks I edited into my question above? Using that line `if any(stock.lower() in....` was the only method I could come up with to search thru an email looking for any occurrence of the fish. Can that be combined with RegEx or is there another way to capture the number following a stock match ?

Comment: I updated to add another capture group containing the union of stocks.

Comment: Ok wow. That is so simple and perfect thank you. To put my own understanding into words; I didn't know that RegEx could take an entire list of strings and scan a page looking for a match, that's very good to know. I also see that the RegEx looks for a string of continuous digits, but the only part I don't fully understand is where exactly in the code does it say "now that we've found a number, append this number to previous stock match"... is the `match.groups()` command responsible for that?

Comment: Its kinda the opposite. Find one of the names we want then continue scanning forward until we find its following digits. I've updated the question.

Comment: In cpython, a regex compiles to a C based state machine that is usually much faster than trying to combine compares at the python level.

Comment: Ok ok gotcha. So it's pretty complex. Thanks a ton for the answer and explanation, I'd upvote it more if I could

Comment: Really quickly: if I want the RegEx to also capture numbers with commas in them, shouldn't it be as easy as `regex_str = '({}).*?(\d+) | (\d),(\d)'`  ? Because that isn't working for me

Comment: That regex adds spaces and also says to match your pattern OR any "digit dot digit" like "2.3". Likely not what you want. If you want to allow commas in the trailing number, you can use brackets to define the allowed character set `({}).*?([\d,]+)` which says to match any combinations of digits and commas.